# Adjective + "of them"

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, pronouns, word-order

My wife and I were discussing whether it is allowable to put an adjective in front of "of them". For instance, I could say "I want 5 cats" and "I want 5 of them". However, while it sounds perfectly normal to say "I want 5 new cats", "I want 5 new of them" doesn't roll of the tongue very smoothly.

If it is incorrect to place an adjective in front of "of them"?

Comment: "I want 5 new of them" seems right. Sometimes adjectives can be used as nouns, e.g. the rich.

Comment: What about "I want 5 of them new"? Like "I want my food dead".

Comment: "It's silly of them to think otherwise."

Comment: "It is silly of them" is a completely different construction and a red herring. And  "the rich" have absolutely nothing to do with anything here.

Answer (score 5):

"*I want five new of them" is ungrammatical for much the same reason it is ungrammatical to say "I want five new of cats".

In "I want five new cats", *cats* is in the accusative case. *Of*, on the other hand, is the case marker for genitive. You can't take a grammatical phrase, randomly switch the case for exactly one word in it, and expect the result to still be grammatical.

The grammatical and idiomatic alternative to "*I want five new of them" is "I want five new ones". Where *ones* is a pronoun in the accusative case, just like the *cats* it is replacing.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with the sentence "I want five new of them" is that the word "new" is an adjective. Generally, the word that comes directly before the phrase "of them" is usually a noun that is used to specify some type of **quantity**. For example:

> - "I want **five** of them."
> - "Out of the hundreds of witnesses at the crime scene, the detective wagered that **several** of them knew the truth."
> - "After marking her students' final exams, the teacher concluded that only **half** of them actually studied the correct material."

Comment: *Several* is not a noun. *Five* and *half* can be, but they clearly aren't here. −1

Comment: So where's the answer in this -- am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

*Five* is a quantifier, like *some*, *few* and *most*. When quantifiers are used to select part of a definitely specified subject (*them* or *the cats*), they require *of* (if you insist on talking about cases, this is the *partitive*, but English barely has cases any more).

So in *five of them*, *five of* is the quantifier, which can't be broken by a qualifier such as an adjective.